# code java convert to php

Tags: java, php

I have a java code that want converted to php .

```
public String getSHA1Hash(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String SHA1Hash = null;
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        md.reset();
        byte[] buffer = input.getBytes("UTF-8");
        md.update(buffer);
        byte[] digest = md.digest();
        String hexStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
            hexStr += Integer.toString((digest[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
            SHA1Hash = hexStr;
        }
        return SHA1Hash;
```

help

Comment: Show us what you've done so far.

Comment: I have had trouble in the API , so I wanted to throw the data json from php to java , but always data is never entered , and I should be able to translate a given java code , and then link full source api java : https://paste.fedoraproject.org/354886/05346571/

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function [sha1()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) that creates a sha1 hash from the input string. No need to convert the java function and rebuild the logic.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a native function to hash sha1 strings:

- [`sha1` — Calculate the sha1 hash of a string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php)

Example from Manual:

```
$str = 'apple';

if (sha1($str) === 'd0be2dc421be4fcd0172e5afceea3970e2f3d940') {
    echo "Would you like a green or red apple?";
}
```

This will give the same output as your Java code would give for "apple".